# Load and reshape multiple csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with the following question.

I have multiple CSV files like below

1.csv

```
ID  Length
1   12
2   23
3   44
3   34
5   11
3   39
7   79
8   45
9   56
0   15
1   35
2   23
3   66
4   33
1   12
7   34
1   21
3   43
6   44
9   55
```

2.csv

```
ID  Length
1   52.1
2   32.2
3   44.6
3   99.1
5   122.3
3   43.2
7   79.4
8   45.5
9   56.3
0   15.4
1   35.7
2   23.7
3   66.7
4   33.8
1   12.9
7   34.8
1   21.6
3   43.7
6   44.2
9   55.8
```

I want to reshape column `Length` by each 10th row and put it side by side in one result.
For example below is my desired output

```
[[12 23 44 34 11]    [[  52.1   32.2   44.6   99.1  122.3]
 [39 79 45 56 15]]    [  43.2   79.4   45.5   56.3   15.4]]
[[35 23 66 33 12]    [[ 35.7  23.7  66.7  33.8  12.9]
 [34 21 43 44 55]]    [ 34.8  21.6  43.7  44.2  55.8]]
```

I tried with the following script but it gives me a type error.

myscript.py

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("Users/Ling/workspace/testing/*.csv")]

start = 0
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1)%10 == 0:
        result = df['Length'].iloc[start:i+1].reshape(2,5)
        start = i + 1
        print result
```

Error

```
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

I don't understand the error. Should I put another `For loop` after `start = 0` so the program will read each file or maybe there is another way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help.

[UPDATE]

With suggestion from @cmaher, I modified myscript.py to be like this

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("Users/Ling/workspace/testing/*.csv")]

df = pd.concat(df) 
start = 0
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1)%10 == 0:
        result = df['Length'].iloc[start:i+1].reshape(2,5)
        start = i + 1
        print result
```

The output is like this

```
[[  52.1   32.2   44.6   99.1  122.3]
 [  43.2   79.4   45.5   56.3   15.4]]
[[ 35.7  23.7  66.7  33.8  12.9]
 [ 34.8  21.6  43.7  44.2  55.8]]
[[ 12.  23.  44.  34.  11.]
 [ 39.  79.  45.  56.  15.]]
[[ 35.  23.  66.  33.  12.]
 [ 34.  21.  43.  44.  55.]]
```

which is different from what I expected. I want to put it side by side like I provided in the desired output.

Comment: It's telling you that `df.index` is a function that doesn't have a `len()` method. What does `df` look like? What does `df.index` look like?

Comment: @Batman the original script actually looks like this where I load a single CSV file only `df = pd.read_csv("1.csv")` . To answer your question I think `df.index` here means the list for all data in 1.csv

Comment: Do you need them side-by-side for visually inspecting them in an interactive shell? Or is there a bigger reason you need them in that specific format? Do they need to be a list, numpy array, or does it matter?

Comment: @jared apart from viewing them in an interactive shell, I want to store it as a new table. For example new matrix formed from 1.csv is placed in column 1 while matrix formed from 2.csv is places in column 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it written, `df` is a list of DataFrames, not a DataFrame, and thus `.index` is a reference to the list method `.index()`. Before your `for` loop, simply add `df = pd.concat(df)` (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), which is a class method specifically built for concatenating sequences of pandas objects.

Edit: here's your code with the added step

```
df = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("Users/Ling/workspace/testing/*.csv")]

df = pd.concat(df)

start = 0
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1)%10 == 0:
        result = df['Length'].iloc[start:i+1].reshape(2,5)
        start = i + 1
        print result
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on `Before your for loop, simply add df = pd.concat(df)` ? Do you mean put the `df = pd.concat(df)` before `for i in range(0, len(df.index())` ?

Comment: That's correct -- I reposted your code with the extra step

Comment: I did what you suggested but it returned the following error --- `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

Comment: Then your problem is in your previous step. What does `print df` return?

Comment: `print df` returns --- `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

Comment: No, you need to determine what is in `df` after the first line of your code `df = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("Users/Ling/workspace/testing/*.csv")]`. It's basic debugging -- since the error is thrown on the `pd.concat` step, it would seem that your list comprehension on the previous line of code is creating an error.

Comment: sorry, thank you for pointing that out for me.i did what you asked. `print df` returns `[]`

Comment: That's an empty list, so my best guess is that `glob.glob("Users/Ling/workspace/testing/*.csv")` doesn't match anything (so the list comprehension does `read_csv` for `filename` in *null*). Test that line of code on its own to get it working, and then the rest of your code should work too.

Comment: Thank you @cmaher. I got it to work but the output is different from what I desired. Do you have any suggestion for this? I already updated my question to show you the current output

Comment: That output is actually exactly what it's supposed to be -- each numpy array is 2x5. They print one at a time as the `for` loop iterates, so what you're asking is perhaps a print formatting question. If my answer resolved your original question, please accept it and then, if you still have a question regarding print formatting, post that as a separate question (numpy reshaping & print formatting are separate topics, and should be addressed in separate questions).